# Sql database on geo redundant storage in Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-storage

We have a SQL Server database mirroring set up on three virtual machines in Azure (1 is a witness). We have all the disks that the VM's use (OS disk + data disk) set to geo-redundant replication.

Would there be any performance benefit if we moved to locally redundant replication instead?

I imagine that having to write to a different data center should add some overhead. Or is it the case that the data is written synchronously to local disks and asynchronously to the disks in another data center.

Any information on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geo-redundant storage writes to the geo-replica asynchronously. There is no loss of performance.

In case the primary data center is lost you can read a consistent but out of date snapshot of your data from the secondary if you chose to enable that option.